# Pandas.replace() doesn't change the data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on the Titanic challenge as a beginner, but there seems to be a problem with `pandas.replace()`. Here's the code:

```
df['Title'].replace(['Miss', 'Mlle','Mrs', 'Dona', 'Lady', 'Mme'], 'Ms', inplace = True)
df['Title'].replace(['Mr', 'Sir', 'Don'], 'Ms', inplace = True)
df['Title'].replace(['Jonkheer', 'Capt', 'the Countess', 'Major', 'Col', 'Dr', 'Rev', 'Master'], 'Ms', inplace = True)
df['Title']
```

When I used the above code, the data doesn't change:

```
Miss            260
Mrs             197
Master           61
Dr                8
Rev               8
Col               4
Ms                2
Mlle              2
Major             2
Jonkheer          1
Mme               1
Lady              1
Dona              1
Don               1
the Countess      1
Capt              1
Sir               1
Name: Title, dtype: int64
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Your code should work. Search the problem elsewhere

Comment: Check your type of columns 'title'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using regex in the following manner:

`df.Title = df.Title.str.replace(r'Miss|Mlle|Mrs|Dona|Lady|Mme','Ms')`

Similarly you can replace other titles as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. But why doesn't replace( ) work?

Comment: I am not sure as to why it didn't work, but you can try df.replace(li, 'Ms') instead of df['Title']. replace